# How to interpret zero degrees of freedom on residual deviance

Tags: residuals, poisson-regression, degrees-of-freedom, deviance

I'm wondering how to interpret residual deviance from a Poisson regression on 0 degrees of freedom?

I have a dataframe with count data on events and number of people at risk for the disease, with ten observations, representing 10 years.

This is the code I used:

```
p <- glm(df$n_events ~ df$year, family = "poisson", offset = (df$log_n_at_risk))

summary(p)
```

The output from the Poisson regression shows  the residual deviance on zero degrees of freedom (see below). How do I interpret that?

> Null deviance: 2.8979e+01  on 9  degrees of freedom
> Residual deviance: 2.1982e-14  on 0  degrees of freedom
> AIC: 69.241

The p-value from the chisq is zero.

Comment: It looks like `df$year` has been treated as a categorical variable.  This would be obvious in the full summary, which will report an intercept and nine more yearly estimates. You have consequently used a model that has one parameter per year, yielding a perfect--but useless--fit.